apt(-get) install: keep automatically/manually installed state
On Debian (apt 2.9.6), when I run apt install on a package that was automatically installed and its version doesn't change, apt(-get) marks the package as manually installed:
# sudo apt install libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0=1.24.5-1 
libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 is already the newest version (1.24.5-1).
libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 set to manually installed.
Summary:
  Upgrading: 0, Installing: 0, Removing: 0, Not Upgrading: 0

Is it possible to disable that behavior, that is, keep the package marked as automatically installed? I know of the option --mark-auto, but this would also mark the package as automatically installed if it was previously manually installed.
It seems that aptitude install libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0=1.24.5-1 preserves the flag, but aptitude is not always installed and somewhat slower.

The only way to do this is to add the --only-upgrade flag:
sudo apt install --only-upgrade libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0=1.24.5-1

This won’t mark the package as manually installed, but also won’t install the package if it isn’t already installed.

This does indeed exactly do what I was looking for. Contrary to what the name of the option seems to imply, this also works for package downgrades.

Yes, a better name might be something like --only-if-installed.
